# Listview search filter result incorrect

Tags: java, xml

When I click list item from search result, return to 0 position. How do I get original position from string?

I have a list with personalized rows, the situation is that when I click on an item I get a good result, the problem is that when I search and click it, I do not get the result I expected.

My code is:

String.xml

```xml
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">SearchViewList</string>
    <string-array name="array_country">
        <item>Alemania</item>
        <item>Mexico</item>
        <item>EUA</item>
        <item>Argentina</item>
        <item>Rusia</item>
        <item>España</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

My code is:

MenuSearch.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/menuSearch"
        android:title="Buscar"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always"></item>
</menu>
```

My code is:
MainActivity.java

```java
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista);
        ArrayList<String> arrayCountry = new ArrayList<>();            arrayCountry.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_country)));
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                MainActivityRespaldo2.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayCountry);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int posicion, long l) {
                switch (posicion) {
                    case 0 :
                        Intent i0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Alemania.class);
                        startActivity(i0);
                        break;
                    case 1 :
                        Intent i1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Mexico.class);
                        startActivity(i1);
                        break;
                    case 2 :
                        Intent i2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EUA.class);
                        startActivity(i2);
                        break;
                    case 3 :
                        Intent i3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Argentina.class);
                        startActivity(i3);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Developing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater  = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_buscar, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuBuscar);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

}

Please help me